# MySql query to get the page usage from a given table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which tracks of the pages visited by a user based on time so for one page
we might have multiple  entries for  a user who access the page, my aim to is to find the page and all its corresponding users with count

For example for  page p1 : u1 :2

Which boils down to p1 has been accessed by user u1 twice

```
    page_usage
 page_visited    User_id
      p1            u1
      p2            u1
      p3            u2
      p1            u3
      p20           u10
      p3            u2
      p3            u1
```

Following are the attempts that I have made.

1st attempt:

```
SELECT  `user_id`, `page_visited`, COUNT(`page_visited`) , `session_date_time`
FROM `page_usage` 
GROUP BY `user_id`,`page_visited`
```

2nd Attempt:

```
SELECT  `page_visited`, `user_id` FROM `page_usage`  
( SELECT `page_visited`,`user_id` 
        FROM `page_usage` AS `used_pages` 
        GROUP BY `page_visited`,`user_id`)
WHERE `page_visited`=used_pages.`page_visited` AND `user_id`=used_pages.`user_id`
```

This was syntactically incorrect. I am new to sql, please bear with me if this is an easy query to solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Page_Visisted,User_Id Count(User_Id) as No_Time_Visited  from page_Uage
group by Page_Visisted,User_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT page_visited, 
       user_id, 
       Count(user_id) AS times 
FROM   page_usage 
GROUP  BY page_visited, 
          user_id
```